# actionPerformed acts on all custom JPanels at once

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm creating a GUI to show output from a database.

Currently I'm adding `CoursePanel extends JPanel` to a `JScrollPane`, to emulate rows in a list. I can't use `JList` with `ListCellRenderer` as I need each row to have functionality beyond a simple click.

Each `CoursePanel` has a `JButton` on it. When clicked, the button adds a new row to the `CoursePanel` and displays some extra information.

However, when I bind an `ActionListener` to the button to increase the number of rows in the GridLayout, it adds a row to every instance of `CoursePanel`. However, only the current `CoursePanel` extra row is set visible. Can anyone offer advice on what is going wrong?

```
public class CoursePanel extends JPanel{
    public CoursePanel(){

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1);

        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel extraPanel = new JPanel();
        extraPanel.add(new JLabel("test"));
        extraPanel.setVisible(false);

        JButton revealBtn = new JButton("Reveal");

        revealBtn.addActionListener(e -> {

            //this line happens for every CoursePanel in the scroll pane
            //meaning every row suddenly doubles in width
            ((GridLayout)this.getLayout()).setRows(2);


            //this only happens for the instance of CoursePanel who's button is clicked!
            //i.e. the JLabel with "test" only appears in the row who's button is clicked
            this.add(extraPanel);
            extraPanel.setVisible(true);
        });

        infoPanel.add(revealBtn);                     

        this.add(infoPanel);
    }
}

//where the scroll panel is built
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(contentPanel);

for(rows in database){
    //...some code to add new rows to the scrollpane...

    contentPanel.add(new CoursePanel(row));    

}
```

Before clicking:

[image: Before clicking anything]

After clicking Bobby's button, note the gaps the same size as the 'test' row under every row:

[image: After clicking Bobby's button]

Comment: >hat is the leyout manager of contentPanel?

Comment: contentPanel also has `GridLayout`, and I update the number of rows in it in the foreach loop at the bottom using `GridLayout l =   ((GridLayout) contentPanel.getLayout());            
            l.setRows(l.getRows() + 1);`

Comment: From the GridLayout tutorial: A GridLayout object places components in a grid of cells. Each component takes all the available space within its cell, and **each cell is exactly the same size**. (emphasis mine). Use a BoxLayout.

Comment: How to learn the hard way. Thanks I'll look into it

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).